# Enlarge Spell with Critical. Which dice do I count?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, critical-hit

The *Enlarge Spell* feat allows you to increase your at-will/encounter burst and blast attacks by 1 if you take a -2 damage penalty per die.

> **Enlarge Spell**
>   Before using a wizard at-will or encounter attack power, you can choose to take a -2 penalty to each die of damage rolled with the power to increase the size of its blast or its burst by 1.
>   You can't use this feat on a power that doesn't roll dice for damage.

What happens if you get a critical hit though?
Would the penalty be -2 times the dice from the original attack? Or -2 times the amount of dice actually rolled? Would this include the Critical dice added with most magical items? What about the dice from an **Empowered Crit** implement?

My assumption from the exact wording of the power is that it is the exact amount of dice rolled with the power, including the bonus critical ones, but not counting the ones that are automatically maximized, however, I though I would double-check.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.

The virtue of 4e's rules is that they work exactly how they say they work. So when Enlarge Spell says that you “take a −2 penalty to each die of damage rolled with the power”, that's exactly what you do: reduce the result of each damage die physically rolled by 2.

This penalty also applies to any dice added by an implement with the Empowered Crit property, since the property's wording makes the power itself do those extra dice of damage, making them subject to any effect that affects the power's damage dice.

Comment: Should I then make this a Question&Answer post and put in the answer myself?

Comment: @PatrickvD Nope- just click the checkbox underneath the two arrows on the left to "accept" the answer.